# How to conditionally apply styles on the component tag based on the visibility of component contents?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

Let's say I have a component like this which contains logic to show or hide the contents inside the component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<div *ngIf="visible"> <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1></div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; } div { border: 1px solid blue }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  visible: boolean;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.visible = this.name === "Stranger"
  }
}
```

And I use it like this in another component:

```html
<div class="container">
  <hello class='hello-class' name="Stranger"></hello>

  <!-- This will not be visible -->
  <hello class='hello-class' name="Not stranger"></hello>
</div>
```

And I apply some styles to the `hello` components like this:

```css
.hello-class {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

The 2nd use of `hello` component will be invisible because of the conditions in the component. But even if the component is invisible the styles I added to `hello-class` gets applied to the component.

I cannot move the condition to show/hide the component to the parent. So I cannot do an `*ngIf` before the component.

Is there any way I can apply this style only if the component is visible?

Here's a link to stackblitz illustrating the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mfrb7j

Comment: On what condition do you show/hide respective hello component ?

Comment: @AkhilChandran: Inside the `hello` component based on some logic.

Comment: Can you add the logic you used to the question?

Comment: @AkhilChandran It is already in the code (the `visible` propperty) and the stackblitz link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are no children, you can do this with a css selector:

```
.hello-class:not(:empty) {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

By using `:not(:empty)` it checks if the element (the host element for the component) has children. If it doesn't have children, then the style won't apply.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Answer (score 1):

Conditional styling with ngClass would work in this situation also.

So in your HTML you would put:

```
<div class="container">
  <hello [ngClass]="{'hello-class': visible}" name="Stranger"></hello>

  <!-- This will not be visible -->
  <hello [ngClass]="{'hello-class': visible}" name="Not stranger"></hello>
</div>
```

So when visible = true, it will apply 'hello-class' styling.

---

*Expanded answer below*

*Option 1:*

**Custom Property Binding & ngClass**

hello.component.ts - make the "visible" property bindable in the parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<div *ngIf="visible"> <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1></div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; } div { border: 1px solid blue }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() visible: boolean;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.visible = this.name === "Stranger"
  }
}
```

parent.component.html - bind to the "visible" property of hello component and apply conditional styling with ngClass:

```
<div class="container">
  <hello [visible]="visibility" [ngClass]="{'hello-class': visibility}" name="Stranger"></hello>

  <!-- This will not be visible -->
  <hello [visible]="visibility" [ngClass]="{'hello-class': visibility}" name="Not stranger"></hello>
</div>
```

parent.component.ts - add the local property "visibility":

```
visibility: boolean;
```

*Option 2*

**Local Reference & ngClass**

Alternatively, if you cannot add anything to the parent.component.ts file, you can do it all in html. You don't need to add the `@Input()` decorator to your hello.component.ts file for this, either. Seems a bit rough, but it works.

parent.component.html - use local reference to trigger the conditions for ngClass:

```
    <div class="container">
  <hello #a [ngClass]="{'hello-class': a.visible}" name="Stranger"></hello>

  <hello #b [ngClass]="{'hello-class': b.visible}" name="Not stranger"></hello>
</div>
```

Comment: This would mean I need to move the logic to show/hide the component (the `visible` flag) to the parent component. Which is not possible in my scenario.

Comment: Can you add a property of any kind to the parent component? Such as   visibility: boolean;

Comment: No, that's the constraint I mentioned in my question. The logic has to be contained within the child component. The option 2 in your answer might work.

Answer (score 0):

Append the name inputs for compponent to variables.

```
public helloNames = [ 'Stranger', 'Not stranger'];
```

Then in component, do as below.

```
<div class="container">
  <hello class='hello-class' *ngIf="helloNames[0] == 'Stranger'" name="helloNames[0]"></hello>

  <!-- This will not be visible -->
  <hello class='hello-class' *ngIf="helloNames[1] == 'Stranger'" name="helloNames[1]"></hello>
</div>
```

Comment: This shifts the logic to show/hide the component to the parent -- which I do not want.